# wgrib2 returns segmentation fault (core dumped) on centos

Tags: linux, grib

I want to use wgrib2 for converting a grib file to txt using this command:

```
wgrib2 gribfile.grib2 -spread textfile.txt
```

I have Ubuntu 10.10 on one of my machines and the above command works flawlessly, but on another machine with CentOS 6.5 it returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` . I already tried to solve the problem using the procedure described on this [page](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) but all to avail.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase your stack size using ulimit?

```
$ bash
$ ulimit -s 4400000
```

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first post I set it even to unlimited

Comment: Try running wgrib with the 

`-g2clib 0`